# Will nonce increase even when the transaction fail?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, nonce

Will nonce increase even when the transaction fail?

For example,

```
nonce=0 -> tx succeed
nonce=1 -> tx succeed
nonce=2 -> tx fail
```

Then I want to send a new raw transaction,
should I assign nonce as 2 or nonce as 3?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Each transaction from an account must have an incremental nonce, **regardless of whether or not the transaction succeeds**. The [MyCrypto knowledge base](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/transactions/what-is-nonce/) provides a good explanation of why Ethereum uses nonces.

Comment: Even in the case of a failed `ᴄʀᴇᴀᴛᴇ2` operation ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/76489